# Get Wikidata entity descriptions via SPARQL, without Wikidata label service

Tags: sparql, wikidata, virtuoso

I found this following code snippet on [opendata.stackexchange.com](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/how-to-output-the-description-of-wikidata-items-using-sparql), which returns name and description of citizens of the US from Wikidata:

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?Name ?itemDescription WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q30 .
  ?item rdfs:label ?Name
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }
}
LIMIT 3
```

The query can be evaluated at https://query.wikidata.org/

I am trying to get a description of a particular entity, for example Q3(life). But it in this case, the [labelService](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service) does not return anything.

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?Name ?itemDescription WHERE {
    wd:Q3 rdfs:label ?Name
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}

LIMIT 3
```

EDIT: I am using Virtuoso and therefore cannot rely on Wikidata Label Service.

Comment: You don't have a variable `?item`. You need to make the subject a variable, and bind it via FILTER. `?item rdfs:label ?Name
          filter(?item = wd:Q3)`

Comment: How did you import wikidata into virtuoso in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT ?o
WHERE 
{
  wd:Q3 schema:description ?o.
  FILTER ( lang(?o) = "en" )
}
```

now, since I am querying a Virtuoso Server with Full-Text-Search capabilities, and it would be better to retrieve the description with other properties in one go.